# linux ps command to count number of running processes

Tags: linux

does anyone know how I can pipe the results of ps -ef | grep ^$USER to wc -1

I already used **ps -ef | grep ^$USER** but know i want to pipe the command

Comment: Do you want to see only processes by a certain user?

Comment: You could, if so allowed, write a program in C (using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) doing appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and using [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You need to read [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [grep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Comment: Consider also using [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or [Python](https://python.org/).... Spend hours in reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and other documentation. Provide some [mre] in your next question. Take inspiration from existing open source code, e.g. on http://github.com/

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question
you want all the running process from a particular user and pipe it to wc ( note its wc -l not -1)

so i used this

```
ps aux | grep ^$USER|wc -l
```

-a : Information for all processes associated with terminals.

-u : Information for processes in userlist.

-x : username (user running this command)

or this can also work

```
ps -u $USER|wc -l
```

for any commands if you want to know the details try `man command` in terminal for example `man ps`